# converting Strategy to Study with alerts

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to convert this strategy

https://pastiebin.com/603682012d391

in a study to provide "open Long" and "close long" signals/alerts.

I modified as follow

```
strategy("Twin Optimized Trend Tracker","TOTT", overlay=true)
```

with

```
study("Twin Optimized Trend Tracker","TOTT", overlay=true)
```

and

```
if buySignalk
    strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long,when=Timerange())
if sellSignalk
    strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short,when=Timerange())
```

with

```
if buySignalk
    //strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long,when=Timerange())
    alertcondition(strategy.long,title="Open Long")
if sellSignalk
    //strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short,when=Timerange())
   alertcondition(strategy.short,title="Close Long")
```

but it does not work, anyone can help me to convert it ?

Comment: Your strategy uses market orders. Strategy alerts released long ago (https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/strategy-alerts-are-live-now-18770/) I have no idea why you doesn't just create alert on strategy directly.

Comment: I have no idea, someone explained me that I cannot add alerts in a strategy and that I need to convert it to a study. BTW it's not my strategy , it's a strategy found in tradingview.

Comment: Recently, the `alert()` function has been added, which can be added to strategies.

Comment: If you want to transform the strategy into a study, then in the `if` statement you need to add a check for `Timerange()`.

Comment: "someone explained me that I cannot add alerts in a strategy and that I need to convert it to a stud" - this is outdated information. Try to create alert for your strategy in two clicks and you can see how it works